# System roms in android phones

Tags: android, root

If i would have a Zte phone and a htc.Both phones had the same specs(i mean the same cpu,camera,etc).What if i root and install an android rom for my zte to htc phone.My htc phone would be recognised as a zte phone?(same id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wouldn't. Unless both phones have the exact same hardware components (by which I don't mean same ability, but same component at a chip level), it is highly unlikely that simply flashing another device's ROM onto yours will work well, or even work at all.

Different hardware manufacturers and models require different drivers at a very low level in the ROM. You cannot run hardware properly using the wrong drivers.